# Permission request to device contact list

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, sdk

In the new versions of MobilePush SDK (8.0.7) is the device being asked for permission to access the contact list? Our App started making this request and we are suspicious that it could be the SDK.

Comment: Which SDK? Is this related to Salesforce? Please [edit] your question to add additional detail (and relevant tags, like perhaps "sfdcmobilesdk-Andorid".

Comment: MobilePush SDKs